# Garbage Appended at the end after Output string C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have just started coding and I was making a program as follows,
I take three strings from the user for eg

```
this is
is what
new
```

And output the first letter of every word in upper case followed by a '.' and a ' ' (Space character)

so the output should be

```
T. I.
I. W.
N.
```

so the output that I get is

```
T. ‚. xWô¿Œ
@ 
I. W. ô 
N. ÿÿÿ
```

I am getting the values but some garbage value also gets appended at the end, I tried putting NULL at the end but that doesn't help.

the code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

int countWords(char* arr);
int main(void){
    int i = 0, j = 0, count[3], num = 0, pos = 0, flag = 0;
    char val[3][50], copyName[3][50];
    for(i =0; i< 3; i++){
        printf("Enter: \n");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &val[i]);
        num = countWords(val[i]);
        //printf("%d word(s) \n", num);
    }

    for(i = 0; i<3; i++){
        pos = 0;
        flag = 0;
        for(j = 0; j<strlen(val[i]); j++){
            if(j == 0 || val[i][j - 1] == ' '){
             copyName[i][j] = toupper(val[i][pos]);
             pos++;
             copyName[i][pos] = '.';
             pos++;
             copyName[i][pos] = ' ';
             pos++;
             flag++;
             if(flag == count[i])
                copyName[i][pos] = '\0';
            }
            else{
                continue;
            }
        }
        printf("%s \n", copyName[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

int countWords(char* arr){
    int i = 0, flag = 0;
    for(i = 0; arr[i] != '\0' ; i++){
        if(arr[i] == ' ')
            flag++;
    }

    return flag+1;
}
```

If there is a better approach to what I want to achieve, please do share. Thanks

Code Edited, please take a look.

Comment: C string must be zero terminated.

Comment: This typically happens when you don't *terminate* the string. Remember that strings of `char` in C are really called ***null terminated*** *byte strings*.

Comment: `copyName[i][++pos] = NULL;` ==> `copyName[i][pos] = '\0';` don't increment `pos`.

Comment: ... and it should have a prototype declaration `int countWords(char* arr);` above `main`.

Comment: `j<sizeof(val[i]);` is wrong - is the storage size not the input length.

Comment: I sugest you read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: By the way, even if strings are *null terminated* it's not `NULL`. `NULL` is a null *pointer*. Use `'\0'` for the string terminator.

Comment: Some things that would've helped you here: (A) compiling with warnings on (B) stepping through the code with a debugger (C) stepping through the code in your head, which would catch errors like incrementing `pos` twice in a row.

Comment: @WeatherVane I already tried '\0' it did not work only then did I change it to NULL and yes I have changed that back to '\0' which did not cause any effect.

Comment: `NULL` is not a character, it is a pointer value. There isn't just *one* thing wrong but several things.

Comment: @MichaelWalz that piece of code was commented out for this question only as it had no relevance here.

Comment: @SuvanshChawla sorry, forget my comment, it's wrong. I just deleted it. But my other comment is still valid.

Comment: @underscore_d I tried everything that you have mentioned above, and regarding incrementing it twice was only for the nature of an experiment. I did use increment only once and when it did not work, then only did I do it twice.

Comment: @MichaelWalz thanks for the link, I shall read it and see if I am missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error in the logic of the program, thank you, everyone, who contributed to this question

the code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

int countWords(char* arr);
int main(void){
    int i = 0, j = 0, count[3], num = 0, pos = 0, flag = 0;
    char val[3][50], copyName[3][50];
    clrscr();
    for(i =0; i< 3; i++){
    printf("Enter: \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &val[i]);
    num = countWords(val[i]);
    count[i] = num;
    printf("%d word(s) \n", num);
    }

    for(i = 0; i<3; i++){
    pos = 0;
    flag = 0;
    for(j = 0; j<strlen(val[i]); j++){
       // printf("  %d",strlen(val[i]));
        if(j == 0 || val[i][j - 1] == ' '){
         copyName[i][pos] = toupper(val[i][j]);
         pos++;
         copyName[i][pos] = '.';
         pos++;
         copyName[i][pos] = ' ';
         pos++;
         flag++;
        // printf("   %d", flag);
         if(flag == count[i])
           //   printf("Put an end");
        copyName[i][pos] = '\0';
        }
        else{
        continue;
        }
    }
    printf(" \n %s \n", copyName[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

int countWords(char* arr){
    int i = 0, flag = 0;
    for(i = 0; arr[i] != '\0' ; i++){
    if(arr[i] == ' ')
        flag++;
    }

    return flag+1;
}
```